# Chain conditions on prime ideals of commutative rings which holds in the polynomial ring also

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

If $R$ is a commutative ring with unity , and every prime ideal of $R$ is finitely generated  , then every prime ideal of $R[x]$ is also finitely generated as $R$ is Noetherian . However , even if the prime ideals of $R$ satisfies ACC (ascending chain condition ) , $R$ may not be Noetherian . But my question is this : If the prime ideals of $R$ satisfy ACC , then do the prime ideals of $R[x]$ also satisfy ACC ? What if the prime ideals of $R$ satisfy DCC , is the same chain condition lifted to $R[x]$ as well ?

Comment: A chain of primes in $R[X]$ lies over a chain of primes in $R$. Since the last one is stationary we get a chain of primes in $R[X]$ lying over the same prime in $R$, a contradiction. (There are no three prime ideals $P_1\subsetneq P_2\subsetneq P_3$ in $R[X]$ such that $P_1\cap R=P_2\cap R=P_3\cap R$.)

Comment: @user26857 : what do you mean by a chain of primes in $R[x]$ lies over a chain of primes in $R$ ?

Comment: When intersect the primes from $R[X]$ with $R$ you get a chain of primes in $R$.

Comment: @user26857 : Ah right ... and how do you say that there are no three chain of prime ideals in the polynomial ring , each contained properly in the next bigger such that their intersection with $R$ are the same ?

Comment: Well, this is an exercise. (I also think I've proved this somewhere on M.SE.)

Comment: @users the result that user26857 mentioned can be found in section 1.5 of Kaplansky's book "Commutative Rings". Alternatively, that result and similar can be found in section 30 of Gilmer's book "Multiplicative Ideal Theory".

Comment: @Xam : I see ... thanks ...